# visual studio for mac provisioning profiles error

Tags: xamarin, provisioning-profile, visual-studio-mac, apple-id

I am using macbook pro. I have xcode installed on my computer. My goal is to develop applications for iOS. For this, I want to develop an application with xamarin framework in visual studio for mac instead of xcode. when i test my app with similator i have no problem. but when I want to test it on my iOS device, I get the warning that the provisioning profile is missing.

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for iosdnm.iOS on iOS.
(iosdnm.iOS)

I created a developer account belonging to the account I use mac. but since I haven't paid the 100 usd he asked me for this account yet, I get the warning that my account is being controlled. My last post may be redundant.

This is exactly what I want to do. I just want to develop an application in visual studio for mac with my apple ID and use it on my ios device. How can I get rid of my above mentioned error?

Comment: you need to create a provisioning profile in order to deploy your app to a device.  This is well documented

Comment: Can I do this with an apple id without creating a developer account, or how can I get a free developer account and install a test application on my iphone with this account?

Comment: go to developer.apple.com and create a free account.  There are a million posts on the internet about this.